# A Derivation in Combinatory Categorial Grammer

Tags: nlp, derivation

I am reading about CCG on page 23 of [Speech and Language processing](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/12.pdf). There is a derivation as follows:

```
(VP/PP)/NP , VP\((VP/PP)/NP) => VP?
```

Can anyone example this please? This make sense if

```
VP\((VP/PP)/NP) is equivalent to (VP\(VP/PP))/NP
```

and

```
(VP/PP)/NP is equivalent to VP/(PP/NP).
```

But they seem at least non-trivial from the text!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CS

Comment: Good old categorial grammars, didn't expect to see them here. I don't expect a come back of symbolic methods in NLP anytime soon though.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I got it. It is simply:

```
(X/Y)(Z\(X/Y)) which Z.
```

In the example,

```
X = VP/PP, Y = NP, and Z = VP.
```